# Linking one param to another (generics, union, tuples)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given an union of tuples like this:

```js
enum EventType { A, B };

type WebEvent =
  [id: string, type: EventType.A, timestamp: number, payload: string] |
  [id: string, type: EventType.B, timestamp: number, payload: number];
```

How does one define a function accepting two parameters: type and payload, where the payload must be of the tuple discriminated by the `type` and returns `WebEvent` type? Currently I have this:

```js
function create<T extends WebEvent>(type: T[1], payload: T[3]) {
  const event = [uuid(), type, Date.now(), payload] as const;

  return event;
}
```

There are 2 issues with this implementation:

1. `event` (return type) is of type `readonly [number, T[1], T[3]]` rather than WebEvent
2. it allows mixing types and payload types, like:

```js
create(EventType.A, 'hey'); // ok
create(EventType.B, 42); // ok
create(EventType.A, 42); // should be wrong
create(EventType.B, 'hey'); // should be wrong
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=47&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALgFQJ4AdhQN5QIIA0UAQlAL4DcAUFYhlgOrABG8SUAvFVFANqIBLCMADOiAIYR0ALijgIzYACcidTLLYgU9AHSEo6cagA2Ae3EATWWKUCQAcwC6UAD7c+g4WMky5kRSpQasAaCFpomDrERIYm5lZ+CsqO1FQAZmAgAMaCpiBQWUrA4ojAADzIUMAAHqUgFiJQTKxhiAB8ABTBssi8AIyOMUZmlj28AEyOAJQ47ll5YkFCohJSnFAAIiXAOiCmAO4dU9Q88yCLwK3r-MveUqr0Q3GWzuKNZ2InUEWIYEr5lyQ1DINEKxVKHU02ki+gA5AALYCoWHHKAAejRUFMAGsqGDtpDWhEdtEoAAWcaojFY3H4iFQ4l6IgUqmYkTw0xgYwWKCKKD7JR5ex4ooEhm6OGI5GsqDsznc3lYAVCoA)

Comment: Your last case doesn't make sense. It's the same as the first. Did you mean to use event type B?

Comment: oh yes yes ur right

Comment: You used `EventType` instead of `EventType.A` and `EventType.B` in `WebEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the discriminator of the union is the event type, we'll make a generic parameter for that:

```
function create<T extends EventType>(type: T, payload: Extract<WebEvent, { 1: T }>[3]): WebEvent {
  const timestamp = Date.now();

  const event = ["very cool id", timestamp, type, payload];
  
  return event as WebEvent;
}
```

then for the type of the payload, we can extract the correct payload type using the generic parameter. If we want this function to return `WebEvent`, then we have to explicitly annotate and assert that the returned event is a `WebEvent`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALgFQJ4AdhQN5QIIA0UAQlAL4DcAUFYhlgOrABG8SUAvFVFANoCWAEwBcUAM6IATvxABzInUyi2IFPQB0hKIn4RgEgIYR0o8BGbBJRdAdQAbAPYGR4qTNkBdKAB9ufIaIS0nIK9MoIqmiY6sQKuvqIRiZQZhZWUDb2Ti6plh7UVABmYCAAxjoOIFClksAGiMAAPMhQwAAeDSCCYrARapgAfAAUisCiyNa2js7KHZIG5Y1MrH1EuACM4+QDvADMHgCUossqiDh+pZUS2vGGxpxQACL1wOogDgDuQwcFPJcg12AfQevAARAhJKhqg4HHYoEJQXE9Hd0KFMJMss58n4-LVEGBJFUgewDD0Tn1qGQaDU6g0hqcoq8tAByAAWwFQzJ+UAA9DyoA4ANZUGkvel9RkxIgAFgATNy+QLhaK6QyNFo5Qr+WJWQ4wHZBFALFAPpJKrIRbUxWrorEoGyOVyKLztbr9YbjabzUA)

Comment: Perfect, I didnt know about that `{ 1: T }` Extract syntax for tuples

Comment: @Wfr It was that or `[any, T, any, any]`. Naturally I chose the shorter form.